# In Windows Phone 8, is it possible to determine source app when Launcher.LaunchUriAsync was called from that source application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

My windows phone 8 app is associated with an URI scheme (`myapp:`). When other apps use `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh701476) and call my uri scheme, is it possible to determine the name or namespace app that initiated the launch?

I have looked around and have not found an official way to do it. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to know which apps launched yours. One workaround is to educate developers launching your app and ask them to add a referrer parameter:

```
myapp://yourUrl?referrer=NameOfTheApp
```

Still, you won't be able to know the name of the app is the caller omits the parameter.